# Ldap: retrieve parent group from subgroup

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to ask you if there is a solution to get parent group from subgroups in LDAP? I did a little search and we can use the filter like **&(objectClass=group)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=PATH_TO_GROUP1)** to get the child groups of the group, but I want to know if there is a way to get parent group from child group.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

All you should need is query AD for the group, and get the `memberof` property, to get all groups that **subgroup** is part of.  The below should be what you need.

```
// assuming your domain is "my.ad.domain.com"
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=my,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com");
// the subgroup you want to find the parents for is "ChildGroup"
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry, "(&(objectcategory=group)(cn=ChildGroup))", new string[] { "memberof" });
SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

// then you can access its groups the usual way
foreach (var group in result.Properties["memberof"])
{
    ...
}
```