# Active Directory - Get the parent (global) group of a local group

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

I am working on authenticating an MVC4 application using Active Directory. Users are assigned to local security groups specific for this application (`Local_Group_APP_myApp_Admin`).

I am using a custom AuthorizeAttribute. The attribute on top of my action methods is:

```
[AuthorizeAD(Groups = "Local_Group_APP_myApp_Admin")]
```

In the custom AuthorizeAttribute class I have:

```
foreach (var group in groups)
    if (userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.Name, group))
        return true;
}
```

This would check whether the user is a member of `Local_Group_APP_myApp_Admin`, which is false (I don't know why). If I get the PARENT (global) group of `Local_Group_APP_myApp_Admin`, I think `IsMemberOf(global_group)` would return true.

How to get the parent group of a local group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have not specified where `userPrincipal` is set, it seems like your problem is `IsMemberOf` only returns true if the user is actually a member of that group. If you need to recursively check for group membership you need to do something more like:

```
using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> securityGroups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups())
{
    return securityGroups.Any(g => groups.Contains(g.Name));
}
```

`GetAuthorizationGroups` returns all security groups the user has membership of.

Comment: I used GetAuthorizationGroups as suggested, and looped through each group and checked if any of the names matches the name of the specific group. It work fine. Thanks

Comment: I found that it is better to use you solution exactly (with .Any). Better performance and less code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can query LDAP to get all the parent groups from a subgroup using the following C#/LDAP query, you can see the full context of the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19822556/167304), you will need to get your LDAP path correct

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry, "(&(objectcategory=group)(cn=Local_Group_APP_myApp_Admin))", new string[] { "memberof" });
SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
```